# How To install ChromeOS Flex on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, chrome-os

How To install ChromeOS Flex Install AWS ec2,
I go through this [link](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11552529) but did not get so much help related to AWS
Using `CloudReady-Home-v83-x64.ova` in my VMware Workstation Player, it works fine, but I want to deploy the new OS in my AWS EC2 instance, how can it be done?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your AWS account support ChromeOS? https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/  "Amazon EC2 currently supports a variety of operating systems including: Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, Windows Server, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, openSUSE Leap, Fedora, Fedora CoreOS, Debian, CentOS, Gentoo Linux, Oracle Linux, and FreeBSD."

Comment: Avoiding the "why" question, if you have it working on VMWare, you might be able to create an image from there that can be brought to EC2. My guess is that this is not going to be a fun process or have a great (read stable) outcome. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html